# Efficient Resolution for 501 HTTPS Required Error in Maven Build for Moving (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 & http://repo.spring.io) to HTTPS?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-2

Need **Efficient Solution** for moving to HTTPS for `mvn clean install` build success

- Have project with numerous internal dependencies which use **http://repo1.maven.org/maven2** & **http://repo.spring.io** for dependency download

Tried following solutions at my end

- Added following **settings.xml** in **~/.m2/** folder. Tried Profiling options also.

  ```
  <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                            https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
        <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
        <interactiveMode/>
        <offline/>
        <pluginGroups/>
        <servers/>
                  <mirrors>
                       <mirror>
                        <id>central-repository</id>
                        <name>Maven Repository HTTPS</name>
                        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
                      </mirror>
                       <mirror>
                        <id>central-spring-repository</id>
                        <name>Spring Repository HTTPS</name>
                        <url>https://repo.spring.io</url>
                        <mirrorOf>springcentral</mirrorOf>
                      </mirror>
                      <mirror>
                        <id>organisation-repo1</id>
                        <name>org-repo1</name>
                        <url>http://org.maven.com/repo1</url>
                        <mirrorOf>repo1</mirrorOf>
                      </mirror>
                      <mirror>
                        <id>organisation-repo2</id>
                        <name>org-repo2</name>
                        <url>http://org.maven.com/repo2</url>
                        <mirrorOf>repo2</mirrorOf>
                      </mirror>
                   </mirrors>
        <proxies/>
        <profiles/>
         <activeProfiles/>
  </settings>
  ```

Still faced some issues for internal jars dependencies in the project.

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.13: Could not transfer
>   artifact com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:pom:1.5.13 from/to cxf-repo
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Transfer failed for
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/netflix/hystrix/hystrix-core/1.5.13/hystrix-core-1.5.13.pom **501 HTTPS Required**

- Added following in **pom.xml**

  ```
        <repositories>
          <repository>
              <id>central-maven</id>
              <name>central https Releases</name>
              <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
          </repository>
          <repository>
              <id>central-spring</id>
              <name>central spring https Releases</name>
              <url>https://repo.spring.io</url>
          </repository>
        <repositories>
  ```

Have read this doc for **maven central repo movement to HTTPS
https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https** but couldn't get any proper resolution for internal dependency issue.

> Some dependencies in my case are still calling http url's of central and spring
>   maven

Comment: take backup of m2 folder and create empty .m2 folder . clean maven repo and start from scratch. I know it is time taking process. but it may help !

Comment: Or i would suggest to mvn  generate dependency tree in your project that will tell us exactly which component is calling this and remove that dependency from m2 folder

Comment: Go through this and find a solution that works for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error

I used the answer from Sumeet Vishwas and changing maven to use the latest version for netbeans.

Answer (score 3):

Either upgrade your Maven version
or

**Restrict the current Maven version to use HTTPS links by modifying your POM:**

*Include the following code in pom.xml of your project.*

```
<project>
  ...
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

taking a backup of .m2 folder and doing clean and install worked for me.