# Maven - doesnt download from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 but trying to download from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

Tags: maven-2

I m trying to run mvn site. I tried even running dependency tree. But still i m getting the following error on console. Ideally it should fetch from https and not from http. How do we get the maven from downloading from https and not from http ?

```
D:\Junit\junit5-examples-master\junit5-maven>mvn site
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< com.mkyong.core:junit5-maven >--------------------
[INFO] Building junit5-maven 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/3.0.0-M4/maven-surefire-r
eport-plugin-3.0.0-M4.pom
Downloading from org.source.repo: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/3.0.0-M4/maven-s
urefire-report-plugin-3.0.0-M4.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.063 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-20T17:14:59+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project junit5-maven: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mkyong.core:junit5-maven:jar:1.0
: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M4: Failed to read artifact descrip
tor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
surefire-report-plugin:pom:3.0.0-M4 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Failed to transfer file http://repo1.maven.org/ma
ven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/3.0.0-M4/maven-surefire-report-plugin-3.0.0-M4.pom with status code 501 -> [
Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Pl assist.

Regards,

Comment: See the answers from [Maven dependencies are failing with a 501 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven dependencies are failing with a 501 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error)