# Error Build Sakai " Failed to transfer file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/zing/cql-java/0.7/cql-java-0.7.pom. Return code is: 501"

Tags: java, maven, sakai

I am getting the following error:

> Error Build Sakai " Failed to transfer file:
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/zing/cql-java/0.7/cql-java-0.7.pom.
>   Return code is: 501"

I tried to delete "`* .lastupdated`" in `.m2/repositoty` but while Sakai Build it more back.

I try add `setting.xml`

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">               
  <repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>Central Maven repository</id>
      <name>Central Maven repository https</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>tomcat5x</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <appserver.id>tomcat7x</appserver.id>
        <appserver.home>/opt/tomcat</appserver.home>
        <maven.tomcat.home>/opt/tomcat</maven.tomcat.home>
        <sakai.appserver.home>/opt/tomcat</sakai.appserver.home>
        <surefire.reportFormat>plain</surefire.reportFormat>
        <surefire.useFile>false</surefire.useFile>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: httpcode 501 comes only when you are using http instead of https instead of the maven repository url. The url in the title should be https
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/zing/cql-java/0.7/cql-java-0.7.pom

Comment: thank you but i will edit where ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven dependencies are failing with a 501 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error)

Comment: Please check if you are referrring to any http url rather https in your application for downloading dependencies