# Can't add Junit to my Maven project (Netbeans)

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, junit

I'm trying to add a dependency to my maven project but I can't get it to work.

This is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hva.dmci.ict.ads</groupId>
    <artifactId>TrainsSolution</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When building my project I get this error:

Failed to execute goal on project TrainsSolution: Could not resolve dependencies for project hva.dmci.ict.ads:TrainsSolution:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.4.0-M1 (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.4.0-M1: Could not transfer artifact org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:pom:5.4.0-M1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.4.0-M1/junit-jupiter-5.4.0-M1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]

Anyone able to help me out?

Comment: Two things as already mentioned https instead of http...and I strongly recommend to use a more recent version of junit-jupiter 5.6.0 (current version)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should update your Maven's version. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59764670/3287786.