# Request to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom Error

Tags: java, maven, xmlhttprequest

i need help.

When Building a the project marks me error when answering the maven, could you help me?

Then I leave the POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<name>VirtualOffice</name>
<groupId>FormatAdmin</groupId>
<artifactId>VirtualOffice</artifactId>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<properties>
    <vertx.version>3.5.1</vertx.version>
    <main.verticle>main.MainVerticle</main.verticle>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>




<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-unit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-jdbc-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <!--<version>5.1.6</version>-->
        <version>5.1.6</version>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-web-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>15.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>newrelic-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-rx-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Launcher</Main-Class>
                                    <Main-Verticle>${main.verticle}</Main-Verticle>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <artifactSet>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>io.vertx.core.Launcher</mainClass>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <key>hsqldb.reconfig_logging</key>
                        <value>false</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>run</argument>
                    <argument>${main.verticle}</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-newrelic</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeGroupIds>com.newrelic.agent.java</includeGroupIds>
                        <includeArtifactIds>newrelic-java</includeArtifactIds>
                        <!-- you can optionally exclude files -->
                        <!-- <excludes>**/newrelic.yml</excludes> -->
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

That is my current POM.XML, they could explain to me how to solve this problem, I already have 3 days investigating.

I am using netbeans, I already have everything ready without errors the other files, I only need this error that I present when I build the project

**Error Log:

### Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom

### BUILD FAILURE

Total time: 1.312s
Finished at: Mon Apr 06 15:56:21 MDT 2020

### Final Memory: 10M/241M

Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.4.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven dependencies are failing with a 501 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error)

Comment: Is different...

Comment: OK - In that case, could you update your question to help clarify how/why it's not related to the recent Maven `http` to `https` changes? That will make it easier for people to help you. (But, having said that, the root-cause error message in your question is identical to the one in the link I provided.)