# Error when creating Maven project from archetype: 501 HTTPS Required

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I run `mvn archetype:generate` and get this error:

```
Error reading archetype catalog http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Transfer failed for http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 501 HTTPS Required
```

I'm using Maven 3.6.3.

I cannot put a different repository URL into the POM file, because when I'm creating a project from an archetype, no POM file exists yet.

I have no `settings.xml` file in `~/.m2`.

Is there something wrong with my Maven installation?

---

The output of `mvn --version` is:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec
Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

`/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec/conf/settings.xml` does not contain the URL that the error message is complaining about.

Comment: I doubt that you have no `settings.xml` ... do you use plain command line? Can you make a `mvn --version` and post what the output is?

Comment: Not in `~/.m2`. I use the plain command line. I added the requested information.

Comment: Running with ```-X``` might give you a clue as to which configuration is used.

Comment: Maven was using an old version of the archetype plugin. When I explicitly specify a newer version, it works.

Comment: This question has already been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven dependencies are failing with a 501 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error)

Comment: No really, since I am using a Maven version that supposedly already knows about the HTTPS URLs. Why does Maven use an old version of the archetype plugin by default? Is this configured somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: override the default http catalog url with an https one, by appending:

**-DarchetypeCatalog=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml**

to the **mvn archetype:generate** command

Background:

When using the *mvn -X -e archetype:generate* command, Maven 3.6.3 seems to use version 2.4 of the maven-archetype-plugin:

```
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin version for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin to 2.4 from repository central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)
```

The plugin uses the remote catalog: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml:

```
[DEBUG] Searching for remote catalog: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
[DEBUG] Searching for remote catalog: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[WARNING] Error reading archetype catalog http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Transfer failed for http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 501 HTTPS Required
```

As of 15/1/2020, maven central requires an HTTPS url:  [Central 501 HTTPS Required](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334)

According to [this JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-358), the issue should be fixed in version 3.0.0 of the plugin.