# Maven HTTPS migration throwing 501

Tags: java, maven, https

There is a private artifact being imported to a maven project. The artifact is being stored in a folder named `repository`. Was using f/w snippet to import the dependency

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>local-repo</id>
            <url>file://${basedir}/repository</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```

The project was last built on December, 2019 using `Apache Maven 3.3.9`. Now the build is throwing following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project target-jar: Could not resolve dependencies for project a.package:target-jar:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
        Failed to collect dependencies at private.package:private-artifact:jar:1.1.1: 
        Failed to read artifact descriptor for private.package:private-artifact:jar:1.1.1: 
        Could not transfer artifact private.package:private-artifact:pom:1.1.1 from/to central-backup (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
        Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/private/package/private-artifact/1.1.1/private.package:private-artifact-1.1.1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]
```

Tried f/w [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59764670/1770181) but no luck.

New repo info in pom.xml:

```
<pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>local-repo</id>
            <url>file://${basedir}/repository</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: I cannot really follow you. You said you tried to change to https, but your logged error seems to indicate that you have not. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Adding Maven Central repo like below doesn't solve the issue:

        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
.

Comment: I don't see any https in your configuration.

Comment: Updated the new pom,xml details.

Comment: So with this POM, which error do you get?

Comment: Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/private/package/private-artifact/1.1.1/private.package:private-artifact-1.1.1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]

Comment: I have other maven builds with no private artifactory that works like a charm!

Comment: Checking private artifactory pom in maven central is dumb, right? Don't know why maven is doing so.

Comment: Maven goes through the different repositories until it finds the artifact. For some reason, the old MavenCentral definition is still used. Maybe you need to overwrite it in the `settings.xml` instead of in the POM. Alternatively, you can switch to a new Maven.

Comment: Tried new Maven version 3.6.3. Not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212850/discussion-between-vishnu-g-s-and-jf-meier).