# Error adding the dependency for apache derby in spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, derby

I am creating a new maven project from starter.spring.io , with dependencies as web, spring data JPA and Apache Derby, even without writing any code, it is showing **error** in POM.xml file!

[image: This is the error]

Please help me through this error.
This is the full file pom.xml.

'''

4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>io.abhinav</groupId>
<artifactId>coutse-api-data</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>coutse-api-data</name>
<description>course api data prohect for spring starter</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.4</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derby -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Maven Central Repository no longer supports communication over HTTP You should add this statement to Your *pom.xml*:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

By adding this statement You update The Central Repository of Maven and use HTTPS instead of HTTP.

This thread can give You more insight into this topic: [Maven dependencies are failing with a 501 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error).