# spring project (from the spring initialzr plug in on the IDE) being Unloadable

Tags: java, spring, netbeans, pom.xml

When i create an spring project (from the spring initialzr plug in on the IDE) on netbeans 8.2 it ends up being Unloadable. How can i fix that problem?
This is the error i find:

Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.4.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.4.3.pom

The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]

The project com.nexus:RegistroEmpleados:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\RobotDyn\Documents\NetBeansProjects\InitializrSpringbootProject\pom.xml) has 1 error
Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.4.3 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.4.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.4.3.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

This is my parent code:

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.4.3

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.3</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

Answer (score 0):

[Maven dependencies are failing with a 501 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error)

Easiest way is to update Maven to version >= 3.2.3.

**Update the Maven version repository:**

Download the Apache Maven binary that includes the default https addresses (Apache Maven 3.6.3 binary). And open the Options dialog window in tools of NetBeans menu bar (Java Maven Dialog View). And select browse option in Maven Home List Box (Maven Home List Box View). After adding the Apache Maven newly downloaded version (Updated Maven Home List Box View), the project builds and runs successfully.

Comment: This fix 100% the indicated error. Thank you for being clear and concise.

Comment: Now it tells me: 
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project EmployeeRegistry: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]