# How to get CodenameOne Maven Project Running in Netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, codenameone

Thx to Steve for the CN1 ant to maven migration tool and video [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/migrating-your-project-to-maven.html). - Has anyone been able to run the Kitchen Sink project in Netbeans after migration?  I follow the video instructions with the migration tool and migrate successfully and it runs from command line with ./run.sh but when I go to run it in NetBeans, I had a lot of 501 (https needed) errors.  Added umer's code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error) and that solved the 501 errors but now get:

1. Invalid POM for com.codenameone:codenameone-javase:jar:7.0.23, and
2. No implementation for org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager was bound.
   while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.

Note invalid POM warning...

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building kitchensink-common 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties (default) @ kitchensink-common ---

--- codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.23:generate-gui-sources (generate-gui-sources) @ kitchensink-common ---
The POM for com.codenameone:codenameone-javase:jar:7.0.23 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
Generating GUI sources
No GUI Entries available
```

Running from command line, invalid POM warning disappears:

```
[INFO] -----------< com.codename1.demos.kitchen:kitchensink-common >-----------
[INFO] Building kitchensink-common 1.0-SNAPSHOT                           [4/5]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties (default) @ kitchensink-common ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.23:generate-gui-sources (generate-gui-sources) @ kitchensink-common ---
Generating GUI sources
No GUI Entries available
```

Running on apache-maven-3.8.1 on MacOSX
Java version: 1.8.0_172
Suggestions welcomed.

Thx, Mike

Comment: I don't know.  I cannot reproduce it.  I just tried again using Maven 3.8.1 (I have been using 3.6.3), did the migration from scratch.  And it worked.    The Kitchen sink migration is actually part of our Github actions CI workflow so it is run every time a commit is made to CN1.
Try running from command-line using the run.sh script that is inside the project.

Comment: Migrated kitchen sink project works using run.sh from command-line so I guess there is an issue with how my Netbeans is configured to run maven projects. Any ideas? Possible clue: POM invalid warning disappears running from the command line (see updated question above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved updating from Netbeans 8.2 to latest Netbeans version (currently 12.3).

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps the method I'm using to detect the latest version of cn1 has issues.   It picked 7.0.23 which was released this morning.   But then it was unable to find some of the jars.

Probably it will work if you just try running the project again as it should be fully propagated to maven central now.

Comment: Please see updated question.  Unfortunately delayed propagation to maven central wasn't the issue.