# Maven Problem - Failed to Look for File 501

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, eclipse-indigo

Relatively unfamiliar with Maven.
Im trying to set up a shared project in my laptop.

I've heard there's apparently a [security issue with the Maven Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error), so, in the `pom.xml`, I added this to the `<repositories>`

```
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url> 
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled> 
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

But, on top of still getting a 501 error, this is what Im seeing:

```
Failed to look for file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt-maven-plugin/2.4.0/gwt-maven-plugin-2.4.0.pom.
```

Why is it appending to the URL instead of replacing it?

```
Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:pom:2.4.0 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:pom:2.4.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to look for file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt-maven-plugin/2.4.0/gwt-maven-plugin-2.4.0.pom.
```

And this is the follow-up message.

Comment: You tagged your question with `eclipse-indigo`, which is more than a decade old. With up-to-date software you would not have such problems.

Comment: Central repository does not allow access via http only it needs to be https instead....See https://central.sonatype.org/faq/501-error/

Comment: @howlger As mentioned, this is a shared project, thus there's a requirement for now of using the minimum spec. Once everything is working well only can we consider upgrading the requirements.

Comment: @khmarbaise I know of that, hence the addition in the ```pom.xml``` as in the question. The thing is that link is still referring to the ```http```one; appending the ```https``` one to it as opposed to outright replacing. That I dont get why.

Comment: Use up-to-date tools and an up-to-date Java VM even for older projects that contain Java code of Java 7 and lower. Please do not waste your and our time by doing retrocomputing and take security more seriously.

Comment: Also upgrade to most recent version of maven (3.8.7) otherwise you won't get it running.

Comment: First remove the supplemental configuration for repositories in your pom file because the output `http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/http://repo.mave..` looks messed up and use the most recent version of Maven ... it's using https by default to access central repository... Furthermore the setence in your question: `I've heard there's apparently a security issue with the Maven Repo,`. is simply wrong. There is no security issue with Maven repository. The issue is that people still try to access with *http* instead of *https*.