# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile on jdk 1.8

Tags: java, maven, java-8

I have a code which works fine when I compile on following configuration.

- provide compile configuration
- clean ~/.m2 folder
- clean install

**Local Configuration - Compiles fine without any error**

```
apache-maven-3.8.4
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-39)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**Bitbucket Runner Configuration - Gives Error**

```
+ mvn -B -X clean  package install -DskipTests
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "5.10.135-122.509.amzn2.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I am getting following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project RdifOnboarding: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project RdifOnboarding: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1224)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

**pom.xml**
this is just part of pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.def.ts.sdp.df.rdif</groupId>
    <artifactId>RdifOnboarding</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.samples</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </parent>

  <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
   </repositories>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>26.1.4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>functions-framework-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-secretmanager</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.sql/mysql-socket-factory -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.jre11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Required for Java 11 functions in the inline editor -->
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
              </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>.google/</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!--
                  Google Cloud Functions Framework Maven plugin
                  This plugin allows you to run Cloud Functions Java code
                  locally. Use the following terminal command to run a
                  given function locally:
                  mvn function:run -Drun.functionTarget=your.package.yourFunction
                -->
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
                <artifactId>function-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <functionTarget>com.def.ts.sdp.df.rdif.RdifOnboarding</functionTarget>
                    <port>8082</port>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your environment settings may be wrong. You claim that your `apache-maven-3.8.4`, `openjdk version "17.0.1`, but you use `mvn -B -X` to get `Apache Maven 3.0`. 5`. `Java version: 1.8.0_151`. I can compile normally using maven 3.8.4. But changing to maven 3.0.5 will fail to compile. (I use SDKMAN to install multiple versions of JDK and Maven, Gradle for convenience Quickly switch between different versions)

Comment: please post full pom file... also you have a compilation error in your code... furthermore using Maven 3.0.5 ?? Really needed (9 years old?) on your JDK 8 is also very old version of JDK8... might be problem of that old JDK 8 version...

Comment: @life888888 sorry for the confusion. `maven-3.8.4` configuration is of my local machine where it works fine. however, on bitbucket runner maven is `3.0.5` and it fails.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven dependencies are failing with a 501 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error)

Comment: @Gaurang Shah, when I use maven 3.0.5, download plugin will fail, because maven 3.0.5 use http not https. I find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763531/maven-dependencies-are-failing-with-a-501-error, and add `<pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
   ....      
        </pluginRepository>...`

Comment: @life888888 I have shared my entire pom.xml. I don't have issue of downloading packages as what you suggested was already a part of pom.xml.